# Selecting data from two tables based on record data containing a character in SQL

Tags: sql, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm having two tables - **ItemMaster** & **PartItemMaster**. Is it possible that if the record contains **PT** in itemCode (column from a third table), then data should be fetched from **PartItemMaster** table else from **ItemMaster table**?

Example (in raw format) -

```
SELECT * (IF (itemCode LIKE '%PT%' = True) THEN SELECT * FROM PartItemMaster)
(ELSE SELECT * FROM ItemMaster);
```

I've to pass this as a single SQL query for SqlDataSource's SelectCommand in ASP.NET GridView.

Any help please? Regrets for the raw / layman's format. Thanks!

...

Answer (score 0):

here how you can do it in `SQL SERVER`:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table3 WHERE itemCode LIKE '%PT%' = True)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM PartItemMaster
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ItemMaster
END
```